# Principal order filters on a POSET

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, filters

I have another problem, but in this one I have no idea how to start.

> Let be $(X,\leq)$ a POSET with a first element and gifted with the topology $\{ (a,\rightarrow) : a \in X \}$ (principal order filters). Show that $X$ is compact.

I really have no idea how to start, I tried using the definition of compact, but I don't know how.

Comment: The set you describe is not a topology, but maybe a subbase for a topology? Alexander's subbase lemma says we only need to consider covers by subbasic elements. But then, how do you cover the minimal element?